# Can I use a variable in this context?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

My code is:

```
import turtle
1 = turtle.Turtle()
2 = turtle.Turtle()
data = [1, 0, 0, 10, 10]
for i in range(1, 3, 2):
    i.goto(data[i], data[i+1])
```

Will this send the turtles to the x and y specified? I am using this in a larger piece of code with a socket server to draw stuff with my friends, but I want to change the code I have currently so more than one person can play with me. I am not sure if using i.goto will work, so any help or suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: what is `1=turtle.Turtle()` supposed to achieve?

Comment: 1 = turtle.Turtle() creates a turtle called 1, so I'm asking if using the for loop will work, to send the 1st turtle to (0, 0) and the second to (10, 10)

Comment: `1` is not a valid variable name; try something like `first_turtle` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create two objects and iterate over them, use a `list`

```
turtles = []
turtles += [ turtle.Turtle() ]

i=0
for t in turtles:
  t.goto(data[i],data[i+1])
  i+=2
```

If you want a number as well, for `i`, you can use an enumeration

```
for (i,t) in enumerate(turtles):
  t.goto(data[2*i],data[2*i+1])
```

Comment: But will this work for "i"? because you haven't got "i" in your code, but you've still used it.

Comment: sorry, pressed 'submit' too soon!

Comment: enumerate(turtles) will effectively give a list of pairs `[(0,turtle[0]), (1,turtle[1])`. So you get both the index and the turtle.

Comment: Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Also see the `range(0, i)` method for python, it's easier than incrementing integers.